# Cannot seem to insert into Binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

When I implement insert and print in binary search tree. it only prints out the first root node. Please help why? Basic implementation of binary search trees, starting out in learning them and moving to more advanced stuff with them, but stumbling at the first step. It looks like it is not adding the nodes to the root node.

```
class bstrees{
class Node
 {
     int data;
     Node left;
     Node right;
     public Node(int data)
     {
         this.data=data;
         this.left=null;    
         this.right=null;
     }
 }
Node root;
bstrees(){root=null;}

public void insert(int data){
    root=insert_node(root,data);
}
public Node insert_node(Node r,int n){
    if(r==null){
        Node n1=new Node(n);
        //root=n1;
        return n1 ;
    }
    else if(root.data<=n){
        insert_node(root.right,n);
    }
    else{
        insert_node(root.left,n);
    }
    return r;
}
public void print_t(){
    print_t(root);
}
private void print_t(Node r){
    //System.out.println(r);
    if(r!=null){

    //  System.out.println(r.left);         
    //  System.out.println(r.right);
        print_t(r.left);
        System.out.println(r.data+" ");
        print_t(r.right);
    }

}


}
public class BST_prac {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bstrees b1=new bstrees();
    b1.insert(5);
    b1.insert(1);
    b1.print_t();

}

}
```

It prints out only 5.

Comment: seems at first glance / not even testing code, that you may want to check for null first, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560679/inserting-nodes-into-a-binary-tree-in-java-question)

Comment: Please read about java naming conventions. Class names start Upper case; you dont abbreviate (BinaryTree is so much better to understand than bstree, isnt it), and you you only use the _ char for SOME_CONSTANTS, but not for variables and method names.

Comment: And for the next question: you want us to spend our time to help you, so please you spend the time to properly format your source code. And finally: having **two** public methods that are both about inserting is simply a super-confusing interface (as you might have seen as I gave a wrong answer first). Thing is: your code is **hard** to read; although it ought to be so simple. Finally: you could **easily** debug this yourself, simply by putting print statements into your code after the relevant actions; or by running a **debugger**.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for the information

Answer (score 3):

In the call which inserts the value `1` into the tree, the call to `insert_node(root.left,n)` creates a new node, but no reference to this newly created node is stored, which means that effectively the tree itself is not changed. The reference should be stored in the parent node of the newly created node; the same applies to insertion of nodes into the right subtree.

Comment: Appreciate it Codor. I changed the code to below and it is inserting and printing properly.

Comment: public Node insert_node(Node r,int n){
  if(r==null){
   Node n1=new Node(n);
   return n1 ;
  }
  else if(root.data<=n){
   root.right=insert_node(root.right,n);
  }
  else{
   root.left=insert_node(root.left,n);
  }
  return r;

Comment: @varunjana Dont do that. If his answer gave the right turn, simply accept it. There is no point in stuffing code in unreadable comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting new node as mentioned by Codor, you are not storing the references of parent node like whether you want to add to left node or right node. always it is creating new node. I have made little changes for making your code work in insert method.

```
public void insert(int data){
        //creating root node if root node itself is null
        if(root==null){
            root =new Node(data);
        } else {
            root=insert_node(root, data, null, null);
        }
        //System.out.println("after insert root data is " + root.data);
    }
    public Node insert_node(Node node, int n, String dir, Node parent){
        //traverse and insert in proper nodes
        //assign left or right child based on some logic i have taken direction as string here.
        if(node == null) {
            Node n1 = new Node(n);
            if(dir.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
                parent.left = n1;
            } else {
                parent.right = n1;
            }
        }
        else if(root.data<=n){
            parent = root;
            insert_node(root.right, n, "right", parent);
        }
        else{
            parent = root;
            insert_node(root.left, n, "left", parent);
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Asif, shouldnt it be:

Comment: `public Node insert_node(Node node,int n,char dir,Node parent){
   if(node == null) {
             Node n1 = new Node(n);
             if(dir=='l') {
                 parent.left = n1;
             } else {
                 parent.right = n1;
             }
         }
         else if(node.data<=n){
             parent = node;
             insert_node(node.right, n, 'r', parent);
         }
         else{
             parent = node;
             insert_node(node.left, n, 'l', parent);
         }
         return root;`